# How to enable onKeyDown?

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I am using the React-date-picker API. I don't get any feedback when I key down whilst the calendar is open. On Day click is working fine. However, the key-down event isn't working when key down after click on the calendar icon to open the calendar. I can't log out.

```js
const onKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => { 
  e.preventDefault 
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('works')    
  }    
}

onKeyDown = {onKeyDown}
onDayClick = {onDayClick}
```

Comment: What, and how, is `onKeyDown` being consumed?

Comment: a bit of context will be helpful. Can you include a bit of the code where `onKeyDown` is being used?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger each event in the related place, like the `keyDown` event. the `keyDown` event for focusable elements like `input`, `textarea` or etc. like below code:

```js
const keyDownHandler = e => {
  e.preventDefault 
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('Enter key is pressed')    
  }
};

~~~

<input onKeyDown={keyDownHandler} />
```

You should pay attention to where you assign the `onKeyDown`? is it focusable or not. because some elements like `div` don't trigger key down event. And there is a tricky way to do what you want. put a `display: hidden;` input in your component and trigger key down by using it.